# I have tried with both parameter and variable to change the query string when calling a REST API

Tags: azure, rest, parameters

I use Azure Data Factory. Here is what I have done.
I have defined two pipeline parameters StartDate and EndDate to be used in query string when I call a rest API.
StartDate as a string with value 2023-11-19 and EndDate as a string with value 2023-11-19.

I have specified the url in Base URl like this
The Base URL = https://api.branas.se/api/bookings/getbookings?skishop=byn%20-%20h%C3%A4mta%20sj%C3%A4lv&pickstatus=all&fromdate=@pipeline().parameters.StartDate&todate=@pipeline().parameters.EndDate to get

As you can see I want to use the value for parameter StartDate as fromdate and the value for EndDate as todate. When I run the pipeline I get a question for StartDate and EndDate and I use the default.
The result is written to a table in sql server but the result is wrong it doesn't use the query string with parameter that I have specified.

If I instead use this Base URL = https://api.branas.se/api/bookings/getbookings?skishop=byn%20-%20h%C3%A4mta%20sj%C3%A4lv&pickstatus=all&fromdate=2023-11-19&todate=2023-11-24
it work as expected. Here I have hard coded the value for fromdate and todate.

When I get this to work I will use EndDate = @utcnow('yyyy-mm-dd') and
StartDate = @formatDateTime(addDays(utcnow(), -5), 'yyyy-MM-dd')

I have tried with both parameters and variables but I can't make my parameters to take effect when I call the REST API. If I use the ARC(Advanced Rest Client) and specify this URL https://api.branas.se/api/bookings/getbookings?skishop=byn%20-%20h%C3%A4mta%20sj%C3%A4lv&pickstatus=all&fromdate=2023-11-19&todate=2023-11-24

I get the expected result. If I remove this &pickstatus=all&fromdate=2023-11-19&todate=2023-11-24
and call the REST API I get the same result as I do when using Azure Data Factory. I can see that preview data is the same as the data that is written to sql server database table. I have google and tried ChatGPT but haven't find any solution why it doesn't work to use parameters or variable to change a query string when calling a REST API.

Many thanks
Tony Johansson

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you are using pipeline parameters incorrectly in the base URL you need to Enclose the pipeline parameter in curly braces e.g. `@{parameter/expression`} as below

**The URL should look like below:**

> [https://api.branas.se/api/bookings/getbookings?skishop=byn%20-%20h%C3%A4mta%20sj%C3%A4lv&pickstatus=all&fromdate=@{pipeline().parameters.StartDate}&todate=@{pipeline().parameters.EndDate}](https://api.branas.se/api/bookings/getbookings?skishop=byn%20-%20h%C3%A4mta%20sj%C3%A4lv&pickstatus=all&fromdate=@%7Bpipeline().parameters.StartDate%7D&todate=@%7Bpipeline().parameters.EndDate%7D)

[image]

You can use **EndDate** = `@utcnow('yyyy-mm-dd')` and **StartDate** = `@formatDateTime(addDays(utcnow(), -5), 'yyyy-MM-dd')` as below:

> https://api.branas.se/api/bookings/getbookings?skishop=byn%20-%20h%C3%A4mta%20sj%C3%A4lv&pickstatus=all&fromdate=@{utcnow('yyyy-mm-dd')}&todate=@{formatDateTime(addDays(utcnow(), -5), 'yyyy-MM-dd')}

Comment: If I use this as you mentioned https://api.branas.se/api/bookings/getbookings?skishop=byn%20-%20h%C3%A4mta%20sj%C3%A4lv&pickstatus=all&fromdate=@pipeline().parameters.StartDate&todate=@pipeline().parameters.EndDate 
I get a result but the result is wrong because the parametrs are not used in the request

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it. I defined two dataset parameter StartDate and EndDate.
The base URL was set to this https://api.branas.se/api/bookings/getbookings
This is everything before ? which start the query string
In Connection for dataset that I called API I set Relative URL to this
?skishop=byn%20-%20h%C3%A4mta%20sj%C3%A4lv&pickstatus=all&fromdate=@{dataset().StartDate}&todate=@{dataset().EndDate}
In copy data activity the two dataset parameter StartDate and EndDate is shown.
I set StartDate to @formatDateTime(addDays(utcnow(), -4), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
and EndDate to @formatDateTime(addHours(utcnow(), 1), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
because utc is one hour before Sweden where I live. Now this works as I want

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).